# how to remove all text after the last recurrence of a certain character

Tags: c#, string, parsing

given any string, i want to remove any letters after a specific character.

this character may exist multiple times in the string and i only want to apply this to the last occurrance.

so lets say "/" is the character, here are some examples:

http://www.ibm.com/test ==> http://www.ibm.com
hello/test ==> hello

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
if (text.Contains('/'))
    text = text.Substring(0, text.LastIndexOf('/'));
```

or

```
var pos = text.LastIndexOf('/');
if (pos >= 0)
    text = text.Substring(0, pos);
```

(edited to cover the case when '/' does not exist in the string, as mentioned in comments)

Comment: ... assuming that '/' exists in the string.  Otherwise you get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: For performance, you could run LastIndexOf, and check if result is -1 to check if string contains the character. This way you only search through the string ones, instead of twice (Contains+LastIndexOf) which can be costly for large strings.

Answer (score 2):

Another options is to use [String.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 modifiedText = text.Remove(text.LastIndexOf(separator));
```

With some error checking the code can be extracted to an extension method like:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string RemoveTextAfterLastChar(this string text, char c)
    {
        int lastIndexOfSeparator;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && 
            ((lastIndexOfSeparator = text.LastIndexOf(c))  > -1))
        {

            return text.Remove(lastIndexOfSeparator);
        }
        else
        {
            return text;
        }
    }
 }
```

It could be used like:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> inputValues = new List<string>
    {
        @"http://www.ibm.com/test",
        "hello/test",
        "//",
        "SomethingElseWithoutDelimiter",
        null,
        "     ", //spaces
    };

    foreach (var str in inputValues)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" ==> \"{1}\"", str, str.RemoveTextAfterLastChar('/'));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
"http://www.ibm.com/test" ==> "http://www.ibm.com"
"hello/test" ==> "hello"
"//" ==> "/"
"SomethingElseWithoutDelimiter" ==> "SomethingElseWithoutDelimiter"
"" ==> ""
"     " ==> "     "
```

Answer (score 0):

On C# 8 and newer, you can also use the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes). Example:

```
    string oldStr = "hello/test";
    int index = oldStr.LastIndexOf('/');

    if (index != -1)
        string newStr = oldStr[..index];
```